# Is custom field option a Valueobject or an Entity in Domain Driven Design

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design, ef-core-5.0

I am using EF Core and I have a scenario where the user can create a custom field and then creates options for that custom fields.

```
public class CustomField : Entity<long>
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public bool IsRequired { get; private set; }


    public List<CustomFieldOption> customFieldOptions;
    public virtual IReadOnlyCollection<CustomFieldOption> CustomFieldOptions => customFieldOptions;

    protected CustomField()
    {
    }

    public CustomField(long id, string name, bool isRequired, List<CustomFieldOption> customFieldOptions)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        IsRequired = isRequired;
        this.customFieldOptions = customFieldOptions;
    }
}

public class CustomFieldOption : Entity<long>
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(256)]
    public string Text { get; private set; }

    protected CustomFieldOption()
    {
    }

    public CustomFieldOption(string text)
    {
        Text = text;
    }
}

public class Client : Entity<long>
{
    public Name Name { get; set; }

    private List<ClientCustomFieldOptionValue> customFieldOptionValues { get; set; } = new List<ClientCustomFieldOptionValue>();
    public IReadOnlyCollection<ClientCustomFieldOptionValue> CustomFieldOptionValues => customFieldOptionValues;

    public Client(Name name)
    {

    }

    public Result AddCustomFieldOptionValues(List<ClientCustomFieldOptionValue> values)
    {
        return Result.Success();
    }

    public Result RemoveCustomFieldOptionValues(List<ClientCustomFieldOptionValue> values)
    {
        return Result.Success();
    }
}

public class ClientCustomFieldOptionValue
{
    public CustomFieldOption CustomFieldOption { get; private set; }
  
    protected CustomFieldOptionValue()
    {
        
    }

    public ClientCustomFieldOptionValue(CustomFieldOption customFieldOption)
    {
        CustomFieldOption = customFieldOption;
    }
}
```

CustomFieldOption seems to be a Value Object as the text it holds is something that doesn't need an Id. But then in terms of store persistency needs an Id to be stored in database on a different table where it can be queries by Id etc...
I am not sure if I shall add it as an Entity because ValueObjects do not have Id.
One other problem I have is validation. If it is an Entity how can I validate Text property. I know validation on constructor is a bad idea. If I validate it in the ApplicationLayer then wherever I create a new object I have to validate that is not empty and the length.
If I forget to add validation in one of the application services and pass null Text then I create an inconsistent state.

Update #1
A Client can select one or many options of a custom field. I suppose these needed to be stored on a separate table ClientCustomFieldOptionValue. In that case is this an entity or a valueobject? And  what about CustomFieldOption. Does it become an Entity? I am quite confused when to use Entity or ValueObjects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to think of persistency details while designing domain model.

According to your description, CustomFieldOption expresses an individual property with no business relations to any other structure, thus:

1. it should not hold a business identifier
2. it should encapsulate its own validations

Meaning it fits the concept of a value-object (validation inside ctor).

When it comes to persistency, your repository model should be capable of storing CustomFieldOption objects in a child table (with DB identifier) referencing the parent table (CustomField objects)

On the query side, repository should be capable of aggregating data from these two tables into a single CustomField entity.

(How exactly you implement such DB capabilities depends on the ORM you choose to work with, EF in your case)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Because it is a list of ValueObjects not a single one does this change the way CustomField Entity is built?

Comment: And also if I introduce a CustomFieldType (Text, Number, Date) to CustomField (A CustomField must have a custom field type) what would CustomFieldType be. An entity or a valueobject?

Comment: How you build an entity depends on your business rules: if for example a field must have at least one option, then you can make the ctor accept a single option and define an AddOption method that appends the list (there are or course other possible solutions but the main idea is to make your entity consistent and self-protected).

Comment: Or you can have you ctor accepting a list of value-objects and perform a null-check.
CustomFieldType does not sound like an entity, it can even be a simple enum (which should be passed in ctor).

Comment: For Entities though validating the object in the constructor and throwing an exception (adding all the validation logic inside the constructor I mean including throwing exceptions with custom message) is it a good practise. From my point of view it is something that needs to be avoided in the constructor. On the other hand though if not validated during the constructor initialization it leads to an inconsistent Entity.

Comment: The other solution is to have private constructor and have a static method within the Entity to create the object where we can add validation checks there (as we do with ValueObjects). Don't know which is of the two is the best?

Comment: Neither is a good practice in my opinion. An entity should be instantiated based on primitives that have been validated in request level and on value objects which are already ctor-validated. Other entity-level validations may appear in methods, including throwing exceptions, when necessary.

Comment: Balue objects are validated either through constructor or static method. primitives though if the entity is created in several places then same validation must be done in all those places. If you forget to do it in one place then an inconsistent Entity is created. I agree that some validations are done in methods but I dont throw any exception inside that entity. Instead I return a result with success or fail (using ```vkhorikov/CSharpFunctionalExtensions``` library)

Comment: If I add a Client object into my domain and each client can select one or many options of a custom field. That would make CustomFieldOption an Entity?

Comment: I agree that primitives should become value objects if they have business validations, however not all primitives require such validations (e.g. person's middle name, which can be simply considered as string).
Returning result values rather than throwing exceptions is perfectly valid, as result values can reflect domain statuses similarly as exceptions.
As for the client and options, please provide a more clear image of object relations.
Can you please share an example for validating value objects using static method?

Comment: I have updated my initial post with Clients and ClientCustomFieldOptionValues.

Comment: Can you assist please. I m stuck for days.

Comment: @pantonis your use cases become too vague for me, I encourage you to deeply learn the differences between entities and value objects, and also explore examples in tutorials. Here's one link: https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/entity-vs-value-object-the-ultimate-list-of-differences/

Comment: I have done already but I am struggling to find any scenario like the one I am describing above.

Answer (score 0):

Just one observation, if you will use Ef Core and the containing entity has a one to many relationship with the value objects, you will have this limitation:

[Owned Entity types, Ef Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities)

> Owned types need a primary key. If there are no good candidates properties on the .NET type, EF Core can try to create one. However, when owned types are defined through a collection, it isn't enough to just create a shadow property to act as both the foreign key into the owner and the primary key of the owned instance

If you are mapping your entities and value objects using DbContext, you usually define an owned entity type for a value object or use a record type.

For owned entities, this creates a column in  your table like this: EntityName_ValueObject (i.e. Person_Address) but this works for a single value object not a collection when you don't know in advance the number of items in the collection.

It is correct that you should not concern with persistence when designing your domain, but is also correct to think that having a value object with an identity does not make sense.

Most important, you should be aware of this potential issue early on.